# gedit plugin development in C

Tags: c, gedit, gedit-plugin

I'm Interested in writing gedit-plugins in C. I've checked [Gedit/NewMDIPluginHowTo](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Attic/NewMDIPluginHowTo)
...but haven't had any luck with it.

How can I get more information about writing gedit plugins in C?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "no result"?

Comment: Curious - who are the target users of gedit? In what market gedit is preferred over gvim?

Comment: @Nate C-K: I mean I found it hard to start

Comment: @ ArunSaha: any new developer come from windows and want to code on text editors not IDE start with gedit.and you can say it's kind of having fun

Comment: "any new developer come from windows and want to code on text editors not IDE start with gedit"

Comment: gvim is available in windows too , so it doesn't depend on where you come from  ... i think gedit is best suited for normal usage and casual programming and (it is really good at doing this).

Comment: gedit is fantastic. i use geany, but if geany didn't exist i'd use gedit. i love the command line, and both vim and emacs in the distant past http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528079/which-text-editor-for-ubuntu-should-i-use/3528110#3528110

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're willing to use Python instead, [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/PythonPluginHowTo) is a tutorial for writing gedit plugins in Python.

Comment: In fact, this looks like the official way to go. It might be harder to write it in C.

Comment: and for this reason I gave the question +50 bounty, because materials in python is available but in C it's not, thanks

Answer (score 4):

The only tutorial is the one you already found :

[Gedit/NewMDIPluginHowTo](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/Attic/NewMDIPluginHowTo)

I know it can be hard to understand in a first view, but if you read it a few times and give it a try with a basic example, you should be able to achieve getting results quite fast.

Is there something specific that you don't understand?

You can also download some examples of plugins available in C:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/tree/gnome-2-30/plugins

Comment: I checked it a lot of time. I was searching for a simple HOWTO or someone has an enough experience but it seems I won't find them. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always email some of the core Gedit developers about your question, I'm sure they have something to give. Try find them via Gedit: Help>About>Credits.

Good luck.